# SFDX and Puppeteer

Tags: salesforcedx, sfdx-plugin

I am trying to use puppeteer in conjunction with the DX CLI.

While I can easily created a `puppteer` object with something like:

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

void (async () => {
    try {
        const browser = await puppeteer.launch({headless: false});
        const page = await browser.newPage();
        await page.setViewport({width: 1600, height: 600})
        const username = 'me@sandboxURL.example.tld';
        const pw = 'mypassword123';

        await page.goto('https://login.salesforce.com/', {waitUntil: ['load', 'domcontentloaded']});

        const selector1 = '#username';
        const selector2 = '#password';

        await page.type(selector1, username);
        await page.type(selector2, pw);

        await page.click('#Login');

        // OTP
        await page.waitForSelector("#emc");
        console.log("found the verification code selector");

        // ...do more things after getting the OTP in email and keying it in
     }
     catch(err) {
          console.log(err)
     }
})()
```

Every time I try this, I have to enter a one-time password sent to my email.

I'm just running it as `node index.js` within VS Code as an immediately executed JS function as a standalone POC for the time being. Nothing added yet with DX commands sprinkled in.

Is the typical strategy for doing this to Oauth via DX CLI, then launching puppeteer API commands to avoid having to login at every test and wait for my OTP to get emailed to me?

Any pointers appreciated

Comment: Might be worth looking at the [sfdx-browserforce-plugin](https://github.com/amtrack/sfdx-browserforce-plugin) to see how they do it. I'm not a node dev by any stretch, but [it looks like](https://github.com/amtrack/sfdx-browserforce-plugin/blob/master/src/browserforce.ts#L28) they're taking advantage of the access token stored in `~/.sfdx/[org-username].json`. Since orgs are already OAuth'd by sfdx, you shouldn't need to do it again.

Comment: Awesome idea, thank you @ThomasTaylor

Comment: @ThomasTaylor that plugin is rather complicated, but I guess I'll try and code-along and see how I can customize. thanks again